# AppEngine Image Not Refreshed when file is replaced

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, refresh

I have an app that users can upload a profile image. if they like, later they can upload a replacement. Works fine in traditional setting but the file url is not getting updated to the new file
 CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file);
Is returning the old image serving url, the path is the same for the new file as it was for the old. I tried to unlink the file before its new version is uploaded but that does not work either. If I am replacing a given file at a given url with new photo content, how do I get the url to serve the new image not hold onto the old one?
When I look in the Developer Console the photo has been properly updated but the url returned by the getImageServingUrl call returns the original file content even long after. In a traditional environment I would append a time to push an automatic refresh but this is different.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file) on the same cloud storage path but with different file content is not supported, and the behavior you're seeing is expected.

You'll need to introduce something in the file name that would make it unique - and then call CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file).

Comment: Thank You. Is there another way to do this or am I going to run into the same issue. Can I CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl() instead? How would I set the public read if I am using move_uploaded_file?  I prefer to adapt the script to another method rather than change the reference system.

Comment: You can use getPublicUrl if you're not using any of the other features of getImageServingUrl(). You can set the ACL in the context options when you call move_uploaded file.  $gs_options = [
  'gs' => [
    'acl' => 'public-read',
  ],
];

Comment: @StuartLangley how are you suppose to replace files then? If I keep making the last file unique, I won't be able to delete the old ones..

Comment: Why can't you delete the old ones?